# Android - Button Keeps overlapping Editext

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext, android-button

I'm making an android app in which there's an activity having an `EditText` on the top and three `Button`s at the bottom. I've set `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` in my manifest to activity so that it gets re-sized automatically when the virtual keyboard is being used. But, as I type in a long sentence in the `EditText`, it's size increases and it goes beneath the `Button`s. I want the `EditText` to expand only upto the free space between the 3 `Button`s and the `ActionBar`.

Here's what's happening -

[image: error_scrennshot]

Here's the XML code of  the activity -

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#eaeaea"
    tools:context=".AddNoteEditor" >

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/noteEditor"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:background="@drawable/card"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="@string/nn"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
    android:padding="12.5dp"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:textSize="19dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="onClickAddNote"
    android:text="@string/ok"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

<ToggleButton
    android:id="@+id/highlighter"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button1"
    android:text="@string/hglt"
    android:textOff="Highlighting Off"
    android:textOn="Highlighting On" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="onClickDiscardNote"
    android:text="@string/cancel"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/highlighter"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the Relative Layout, in which EditText fills up the entire available space (in this layout) when text is long enough. As a result it fills also the space that is under those buttons.

You have basically two solutions.

1. Add a bottom margin to your EditText that will be equal in size to the height of a button.
2. Use Linear Layout(s) instead of Relative Layout (one Linear Layout to replace the Relative Layout - a vertical one, and another Linear Layout - horizontal - to place those buttons side by side).

Answer (score 0):

maybe you must try your `EditText` as scrollable:

for horizontal scroll:

```
 <EditText
      android:scrollHorizontally="true"
 ../>
```

for vertical scroll:

```
<EditText
     android:scrollbars = "vertical"
../>
```